# Implement abstract behaviour just once... trait as contract, abstract class as concrete-helper

Tags: scala, generics, abstraction, generic-programming, traits

I'm currently thinking about refactoring my personal linear-algebra package.
One thing that really bothers me is:

Currently I only support Vectors and Matrices that consist of `float`s. Now I'd like to add in support for `int`s, `double`s and possibly even for `boolean`s, but I'll have to think about that.

One thing tho: I do not want to write code multiple times. In fact, that's one thing I truly hate in programming. I want a single source of responsibility for a certain code/behaviour.

For most, well, *all* operations a Vector has there is a certain pattern. It doesn't matter if I add two Two-dimensional-vectors that hold `int`s or `float`s, the operation is always the same.

Now, naively I though "Well, how difficult can this be?!" Turns out, for me as a Scala-noobie, it's not that easy.

I began with:

```
trait Vector[Vec <: Vector]
{
  def add(v: Vec): Unit
  def subtract(v: Vec): Unit
  def multiply(v: Vec): Unit
  def multiply(s: Numeric): Unit
  def dot(v: Vec): Numeric
  def length(): Numeric
  def distance(v: Vec): Numeric
  def normalise(): Unit
  def divide(length: Numeric): Unit
  def toArray(): Array[Numeric]
}
```

My **thoughts**: Adding in a bound would help me, as I proceed.

Example:

```
abstract class Vector2(var x: Numeric, var y: Numeric) extends Vector[Vector2]
{
  override def add(v: Vector2): Unit =
  {
    this.x += v.x
    this.y += v.y
  }
//...
}
```

Then I wanted to create sub-types like:

```
class IntVector2(var x: Int, var y: Int) extends Vector2
```

and be done with it.

Problem begins here:

```
abstract class Vector2(var x: Numeric, var y: Numeric) extends Vector[Vector2]
{
  override def add(v: Vector2): Unit =
  {
    this.x += v.x // **here is the problem **
    this.y += v.y
  }
//...
}
```

It says

> Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Numeric

I thought I'd be brainy by using Numeric as the upper-bound, as I assumed an addition would be defined for all... how wrong was I?

How can I solve this? Any ideas?

Also, before I forget...

Assume cases where I need to use a helper, like `math.sqrt(...)`. What to do there?

Currently (only implemented for `float`s, mind!) I do this:

```
def length(): Float =
{
  math.sqrt(x * x + y * y).toFloat
}
```

Now if I want to have the same for `double`s and `int`s, how can I make this generic? Like, without `.toFloat`

Also, I'm fully aware that with `boolean`s I would get a problem, as some operations are simply not defined at all... No reason to freak out, I hope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider looking inside scala standard collection library. Give attention to all classes that ends with *Like*: TraversableLike, SeqLike, SetLike and so on. They use [higher-order types](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#higher) and [typeclass polymorphism](http://blog.jaceklaskowski.pl/2015/05/15/ad-hoc-polymorphism-in-scala-with-type-classes.html). Notice all uses of implicit arguments to methods like `def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That`.

[Here](https://github.com/non/spire) is the project that provide many numeric abstractions and may be used as a reference.

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid implicits until I really, really understand them. They are just like a blackbox to me.

Comment: There is a sad fact: scala awesome collection library could not be so awesome without them. You need not to use implicits everywhere neglecting all other expressive means as it the shapeless (and other haskell inspired libraries) does. But sometimes they are indespensible